# Формат возвращаемого значения preg_match

Tags: php

Мне нужно забрать из поля в preg_match символы такого формата: 3 (346) 553-45-34

Пытаюсь сделать так, но проверка не проходит дальше.

```
$is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9]{6,20}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']);
```

Как я понимаю, я не забираю символы пробела, тире и скобок.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Не могу разобраться :(

Comment: нужно вытащить номер или проверить на этот формат? в первом случае можно вытащить все цифры и отформатировать как надо. во втором `^\d+\s*\(\d+\)\s*\d{3}(-\d{2}){2}`

Comment: @splash58 нужно проверить на этот формат

Comment: я дописал комментарий

Comment: @splash спасибо, а как еще поставить лимит на минимальное и максимальное количество?

У меня есть поле input с маской, я оттуда вытаскиваю значение и проверяю на php

Comment: {min,max} - например {1,3}

Comment: @splash58 пишу так, не срабатывает :(

$is_correct = preg_match('/^\d+\s*\(\d+\)\s*\d{3}(-\d{2}){6,12}/', $_POST['billing_phone']);

Comment: что такое 6, 12 - группа минус и две цифры у вас повторяются всего дважды

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Aex3CO/1